# Error:You must supply a layout_width attribute error. Although I've supplied it

Tags: android, android-layout

Here's the layout which is causing problems.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!-- Drawer Layout -->

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <!--Main content-->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/mtoolbar"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


        <TextView
            android:text="@string/hello_world"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/mtoolbar"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <!--Navigation Drawer-->
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/main_drawer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Here is the `drawer_header.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:background="@drawable/header"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="bottom">

    <TextView
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World "
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

And here's the logcat output

```
06-15 21:38:05.125 14798 14798 I   art                                          Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
06-15 21:38:05.323 14798 14798 W   System                                       ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/xyz.sayangoswami.opoforums-2/lib/arm
06-15 21:38:05.472 14798 14798 I   AppCompatViewInflater                        app:theme is now deprecated. Please move to using android:theme instead.
06-15 21:38:05.515 14798 14798 D   AndroidRuntime                               Shutting down VM
06-15 21:38:05.520 14798 14798 E   AndroidRuntime                               FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-15 21:38:05.520 14798 14798 E   AndroidRuntime                               Process: xyz.sayangoswami.opoforums, PID: 14798
06-15 21:38:05.520 14798 14798 E   AndroidRuntime                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{xyz.sayangoswami.opoforums/xyz.sayangoswami.opoforums.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #39: Binary XML file line #39: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
06-15 21:38:05.520 14798 14798 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
06-15 21:38:05.520 14798 14798 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
06-15 21:38:05.520 14798 14798 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
06-15 21:38:05.520 14798 14798 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
06-15 21:38:05.520 14798 14798 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-15 21:38:05.520 14798 14798 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
06-15 21:38:05.520 14798 14798 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
06-15 21:38:05.520 14798 14798 E   AndroidRuntime                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
06-15 21:38:05.520 14798 14798 E   AndroidRuntime                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
06-15 21:38:05.520 14798 14798 E   AndroidRuntime                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
06-15 21:38:05.520 14798 14798 E   AndroidRuntime                               Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #39: Binary XML file line #39: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
06-15 21:38:05.520 14798 14798 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
06-15 21:38:05.520 14798 14798 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
06-15 21:38:05.520 14798 14798 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
06-15 21:38:05.520 14798 14798 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280)
06-15 21:38:05.520 14798 14798 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
06-15 21:38:05.520 14798 14798 E   AndroidRuntime                               at xyz.sayangoswami.opoforums.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28)
06-15 21:38:05.520 14798 14798 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
06-15 21:38:05.520 14798 14798 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
06-15 21:38:05.520 14798 14798 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
06-15 21:38:05.520 14798 14798 E   AndroidRuntime                               ... 9 more
06-15 21:38:05.520 14798 14798 E   AndroidRuntime                               Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #39: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
06-15 21:38:05.520 14798 14798 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
06-15 21:38:05.520 14798 14798 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764)
06-15 21:38:05.520 14798 14798 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
06-15 21:38:05.520 14798 14798 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
06-15 21:38:05.520 14798 14798 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
06-15 21:38:05.520 14798 14798 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
06-15 21:38:05.520 14798 14798 E   AndroidRuntime                               ... 17 more
06-15 21:38:05.520 14798 14798 E   AndroidRuntime                               Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
06-15 21:38:05.520 14798 14798 E   AndroidRuntime                               at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
06-15 21:38:05.520 14798 14798 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
06-15 21:38:05.520 14798 14798 E   AndroidRuntime                               ... 22 more
06-15 21:38:05.520 14798 14798 E   AndroidRuntime                               Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: You must supply a layout_width attribute.
06-15 21:38:05.520 14798 14798 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
06-15 21:38:05.520 14798 14798 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
06-15 21:38:05.520 14798 14798 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter.inflateHeaderView(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:189)
06-15 21:38:05.520 14798 14798 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.inflateHeaderView(NavigationView.java:263)
06-15 21:38:05.520 14798 14798 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:174)
06-15 21:38:05.520 14798 14798 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:96)
06-15 21:38:05.520 14798 14798 E   AndroidRuntime                               ... 24 more
06-15 21:38:05.520 14798 14798 E   AndroidRuntime                               Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Binary XML file line #2: You must supply a layout_width attribute.
06-15 21:38:05.520 14798 14798 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.content.res.TypedArray.getLayoutDimension(TypedArray.java:709)
06-15 21:38:05.520 14798 14798 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.setBaseAttributes(ViewGroup.java:6889)
06-15 21:38:05.520 14798 14798 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams.<init>(ViewGroup.java:7071)
06-15 21:38:05.520 14798 14798 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams.<init>(LinearLayout.java:1911)
06-15 21:38:05.520 14798 14798 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.widget.LinearLayout.generateLayoutParams(LinearLayout.java:1816)
06-15 21:38:05.520 14798 14798 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.widget.LinearLayout.generateLayoutParams(LinearLayout.java:1815)
06-15 21:38:05.520 14798 14798 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:502)
06-15 21:38:05.520 14798 14798 E   AndroidRuntime                               ... 29 more
```

Although I've supplied the layout_width parameter for the `DrawerLayout` it is still showing an error.

If it helps, I'm using AppCompat v7 and Design support libraries with compileSdkVersion 21 and buildToolsVersion 21.1.0

Thanks in advance.

## The problem is resolved.

The problem was that I had `http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android` in capitals that is `HTTP://SCHEMAS.ANDROID.COM/APK/RES/ANDROID` in `drawer_header.xml` line 2 .

Comment: The error says it is `inflateHeaderView()` - can you include your `drawer_header.xml`?

Comment: what is at line 2 of `NavigationView`'s xml file?

Comment: @ianhanniballake Sure wait a min.

Comment: @Vucko I've added it. Please check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be seeing errors in your `drawer_header.xml` file, the namespace should not be all caps:

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

Not:

```
xmlns:android="HTTP://SCHEMAS.ANDROID.COM/APK/RES/ANDROID"
```

Comment: I've a question though. Should namespaces be case sensitive?

Comment: They obviously are, but whether they should , who knows? :D Anyway, all caps looks like you're shouting a namespace :D

Comment: @Sayan98 True, I don't think they *should* be, but they are.

Comment: @Vucko yeah shouting!  ;-)